# I'm fairly certain a high rep user retaliated against me because I didn't understand or agree with their answer. What can I do?

Tags: support

I posted a [question about an electrical box](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/187047/105413) and one of the answers by a high rep user talked about switches and yokes. I wasn't sure what a yoke was, so I asked, and when that was answered, I commented that I didn't think the answer was addressing my question.

Within a minute, I watched a down vote come in on both of my questions on site. I hardly think that's coincidence, as my other question has not had activity in a while. This doesn't seem fair. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: I've noticed the same too on my account. Thank you for your post as I thought I was being paranoid.

Answer (score 3):

@lucasvw - It is hard to control the actions of others. I may suggest rather than dwelling on the apparent unfairness of those actions try to ignore it and move on.

In fact the actual reputation penalty of downvotes is really small and you can easily establish yourself here by continuing to participate posting questions and even answering from time to time when you have some experience with one thing or another. Reputation buildup will result.

Comment: That's kind of what I figured the answer would be. It's just hard to stomach when the down votes come from a user with 50k rep when I have 140.

Comment: @lucasvw - When dealing online you would do well to not get upset at things like this that are in fact pretty minor. Avoid being combative and creating challenges and you will relax much more.

Comment: Could you explain how I have been combative? I simply think the user didn't answer my question and said as much.

Comment: I did not say you were combative. I said that those were things to avoid because those types of actions often cause others to do things we do not like.